# Call my account list in render using map function in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

I don't know how to display a list of items in `render()`. I mostly use an array where the list is stored and get items from this array in render.

Here is my code:

```
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }



handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let { items } = this.state;
        const token =  localStorage.getItem('toktok');
        fetch(`${API}/api/accounts`,{
            headers :{
                'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, 
            }
        })

        .then(results => {
            return results.json();
        })

        .then(data => {
            const temp = data.result;
            items = temp;
            // localStorage.setItem('mymy',  "fiss");
            console.log(items);
            console.log(items.length); 
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("erroooor : ",err);
        });}
```

and this is the `render()` in which the elements are called

```
 render(){
var { items} = this.state;
  {
      items.length > 0 ? items.map(item => {
      const {nom, prenom, email, tel} = item;
      return <div className="ohayo" key={email}>
       <p>{email}</p>
       <p>{nom}</p>
       <p>{prenom}</p>
       <p>{tel}</p>
      </div>
      }) : "null"
}      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all you really need to do is set your items to state after you fetch them.

```
.then(data => {
  // localStorage.setItem('mymy',  "fiss");
  this.setState({ items: data.result });
})
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer :)

it gives me an error :

```TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined```

Comment: Interesting, what get's logged on the two lines before `this.setState`?

Comment: ```console.log(items);```  return : all my data, in this format : 
```0: {dateCreation: "2019-10-09T21:54:18.491Z", resetpasswordtoken: null, resetpasswordexpires: null, role: "admin", enable: true, …}
1:...
2: ...```

```console.log(items.length);``` returns : 3

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing `let { items } = this.state;` within `handleSubmit`? If not, I'd remove that line and only set items in your `then` block

Comment: i have these error if i remove 
```let { items } = this.state;``` : 

  Line 72:13:  'items' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 74:25:  'items' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 75:25:  'items' is not defined  no-undef

because i call it in .then(...)

Comment: See my updated answer to fully remove the `items` variable

Comment: still not working, it always shows "null". Is my render() correct ?

Comment: Can you console log `data.result`?

Comment: IT WORKS!! when i click, it shows all the accounts:    
```0: {dateCreation: "2019-10-09T21:54:18.491Z", resetpasswordtoken: null, resetpasswordexpires: null, role: "admin", enable: true, …} 1:... 2: ... 

Thank you !